# Putting two dimensional array into json

Tags: json

recently i've faced some dificulties in putting two dimensional array into json. It's gonna be used as template, so it will have limited and constant amount of rows and columns.

picrelated:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBAf5.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something similar to:

```
[
 [{"name":"aa"},{"name":"bb"}],
 [{"name":"cc"},{"name":"dd"}]
]
```

?

Comment: Yeah, but it scares me while i'm going to have about 100+ values.

And pic related!

Comment: Then you can try sparsed arrays or even better - different 1-dim arrays with objects with (x,y) coord for different object types you have on your map (if get it correct)

Comment: Not sure that it will help.
The purpose is to use these jsons as metadata for visualisation and using 9 times more files to parse will be better for perfomance.

So as I got your idea I'll split each template into 9 pieces, each of it describing one separate string.